# AdView layout takes up whole screen

Tags: android, android-layout, admob

I have the following XML layout:

```
            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent">

                <ScrollView
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:fillViewport="true"
                    android:layout_above="@+id/adcontent1"
                    android:background="#0000FF">

                    <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tempview"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

                </ScrollView>

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="#FF0000"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:id="@+id/adcontent1" >

                    <com.google.ads.AdView
                        xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
                        android:id="@+id/adview1"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        app:adSize="BANNER"
                        app:adUnitId="lah-di-da"
                        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

                    </com.google.ads.AdView>

                 </RelativeLayout>

            </RelativeLayout>
```

The problem is, that for some reason, the `wrap_content` for the `AdView` `RelativeLayout` height attribute causes the whole `RelativeLayout` to take up the whole screen. If I set a hard value (`50px`) then I get the `ScrollView` taking up the whole screen - 50px (Like I want, except that the `RelativeLayout` height should be equal to the `AdView` height. Does anyone know why the `AdView` forces the parent `RelativeLayout` to fill the screen?

**Note:** There are layouts behind these, but they have no influence on this specific issue (As tested by setting height = 50px).

Comment: try to fix the size dynamically.usually the view will occupy whole layout.get id for view and set layout params dynamically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to set the height of the ad to '50dp' and post your results

Comment: Wow...works. But I would prefer a dynamic way if possible, as I do not know the size of the ads that I will be receiving.

Comment: what type is your ad container? Is it a textbox, textview, ext. I can write out example code if you tell me that.

Comment: Its an AdView from the Google AdMob api...I think your 50dp will work fine. Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 1):

Since `android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"` wont work with `wrap_content`( it works with `fill_parent` as it knows the area in which it needs to be centered). Remove the CenterHorizontal code And use wrap_content instead of providing a height value which will not allow to provide Ads dynamically.